# Layout issue with Grids:SkeletonFramework

Tags: html, css, skeleton-css-boilerplate

I am using [Skeleton](http://getskeleton.com) Framework, and the layout I made using the grid system is like this:

```
 <div class="container">
        <!-- columns should be the immediate child of a .row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="three columns">
                <br>
            </div>
            <div class="six columns" style="margin-top: 25px">
               <img src="img/okay.jpg" width="50px" style="display:inline"/>
                <p id="title" style="display:inline">{{title}}</p>
                <p id="excerpt" style="display:inline">{{description}}</p>
                <div id="describe me" style="display:inline"><span style="display:inline">{{name}}</span><span style="display:inline">{{date}}</span></div>
            </div>
            <div class="three columns">
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It shows something like this:

[image]

But what I want is something like this:[image]

How can this be achieved?

Result: [image]

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your code, although there are many alternate solutions for this, maybe even in their documentation.

1. First, try to avoid using inline styles.
2. Wrap your content inside a
       class.
3. Vetical align the image to the top.
4. Remove the default margin
       on the paragraph items.

```css
.desc { 
  display: inline-block;
 }

.desc p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
 }

.six img {
  vertical-align: top;
 }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <!-- columns should be the immediate child of a .row -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="three columns">
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="six columns">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/50x75" width="50px" />
      <div class="desc">
        <p id="title">{{title}}</p>
        <p id="excerpt">{{description}}</p>
        <div id="describe me"><span>{{name}}</span><span>{{date}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="three columns">
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, it is dependent on other code as well. I had to respond to the code you posted. Show the code in JSfiddle.

Comment: There is no other code. This is the page. I even added !important to the cssbutit doesnt work.

Comment: Please create a JSfiddle of the code that is giving your latest output. BTW You wanted the same layout as posted in my answer right?

Comment: The layout you created works in jsfiddle, but not otherwise. I will create a jsfiddle and editthe question.

Comment: Can a `table` be a better option in this?

Comment: Nope, don't use tables for these type of layouts.

Comment: Okay. I will post the jsfiddle.

Comment: So, here is the problem: If you open the jsFIddle and paste the above mentioned code, and change the description from {{description}} to something like this : `THis is the describtive text for the above mentionedtitle. It is written here to give you an understanding about this.`, and then run the fiddle, it will not work.

Comment: As soon as the text increases a minimum number of characters, the image shifts.